# CSS variables not working on multiple SVG gradients

Tags: jquery, css, variables, svg, css-variables

I have some jquery that is appending an SVG to any div with class `.fade-top-onbottom` and then using CSS variables to style the SVG gradients. The css variables work on the first SVG on the page, but not on the others.

This is due to the #fadeDown in the linearGradient. If I set a unique #, it works (which makes sense).

How can I get jQuery to insert a unique ID for each gradient that gets appended?

```js
$(".fade-top-onbottom").append("<div class='dh-bottom-divider-fade-top'><svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 1280 140' preserveAspectRatio='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><defs><linearGradient id='fadeDown' x1='0' x2='0' y1='0' y2='1'><stop offset='0%' stop-color='var(--bottom-divider-color, #999)'/><stop offset='100%' stop-color='var(--bottom-divider-color, #999)' stop-opacity='0'/></linearGradient></defs><path d='M 0 0 L 0 140 L 1280 140 L 1280 0 Z' fill='url(#fadeDown)'/></svg></div>");
```

```css
body {
  background:#000;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.yellow {
  --bottom-divider-color:yellow;
}
.red {
  --bottom-divider-color:red;
}
.blue {
  --bottom-divider-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='fade-top-onbottom yellow'></div>
<div class='fade-top-onbottom red'></div>
<div class='fade-top-onbottom blue'></div>
```

Comment: you focused on the CSS variable but in reality there is no issue with CSS but all the SVG are using the same gradient due to the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the elements and add an index to each `id`.

```js
var gradients = $(".fade-top-onbottom");

gradients.each(function(index) {
 $(this).append("<div class='dh-bottom-divider-fade-top'><svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 1280 140' preserveAspectRatio='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><defs><linearGradient id='fadeDown" + index + "' x1='0' x2='0' y1='0' y2='1'><stop offset='0%' stop-color='var(--bottom-divider-color, #999)'/><stop offset='100%' stop-color='var(--bottom-divider-color, #999)' stop-opacity='0'/></linearGradient></defs><path d='M 0 0 L 0 140 L 1280 140 L 1280 0 Z' fill='url(#fadeDown" + index + ")'/></svg></div>");
});
```

```css
body {
  background:#000;
}

.yellow {
  --bottom-divider-color:yellow;
}
.red {
  --bottom-divider-color:red;
}
.blue {
  --bottom-divider-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='fade-top-onbottom yellow'></div>
<div class='fade-top-onbottom red'></div>
<div class='fade-top-onbottom blue'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @steven-b. That works like a charm. Much appreciated!